# Linq2db.EntityFramework dependency is giving error

Tags: entity-framework-core, linq2db

```
var query = 
from s in context.AssetStatusRecord.ToLinqToDB()  // switch LINQ Provider
where s.Speed != 0 
    && s.CreationUtcTime <= endTime
    && s.CreationUtcTime >= startTime
    && s.AssetId == assetId
orderby s.CreationUtcTime
select new 
{
    s.CreationUtcTime,  
    s.Speed,
    diff = s.CreationUtcTime - 
        Sql.Ext.Lag(s.CreationUtcTime)
            .Over()
            .OrderBy(s => s.CreationUtcTime)
            .ToValue()
};
```

var result = query.ToList();

I am using this query but getting an error on ToLinqToDB() Line .
I have installed linq.EntityFramework linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore 3.7.0 but still cannot include this class dependency.
My Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational version is 3.1.6

Comment: Can you update EF Core 3.x to latest 3.1.23? linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore requires at least 3.1.21 version

Comment: Client is refusing the update

Comment: I have successfully installed 3.7.0 version alongside with EF Core 3.1.6

Comment: 3.7 is getting installed but the error remains same

Comment: First, update EF Core, then check how it works. If it works, we will find way how to install package.

Comment: Released  `linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore` 3.18.0, which works with EF Core 3.1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Released linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore 3.18.0, which works with EF Core 3.1.6